# Send a string from one component to another page in React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-props, strapi

I am using React for the very first time and I just started coding. I have made this e-commerce website using React, Strapi and Redux for cart (mostly using follow along). Now I am stuck with search functionality.

What I did was I had my search input in Navbar for search and separate page for search which would be navigated to './search' onSubmit form. I am trying to send the search query in navbar to the search page as plain text, which I would then use to filter the contents in search page.

Here is my navbar component:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './Navbar.css';
import { IoSearchOutline } from "react-icons/io5";
import { HiOutlineUserCircle } from "react-icons/hi2";
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Cart from '../Cart/Cart';
import Menu from '../Menu/Menu';
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import useFetch from '../../hooks/useFetch';
import Search from '../../pages/SearchC/Search';

const Navbar = () => {

  const [showMenu, setShowMenu] = useState(false);
  const products = useSelector(state => state.cart.products);

  const [query, setQuery] = useState("");
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const onChange = (e) => {
    setQuery(e.target.value);
  }
  const submitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    navigate(`/search`);
  }
  let { data } = useFetch(`/products?[filters][title][$contains]=${query}`);
  if (!query.length) {
    data = null;
  }
  // hola


  return (
    <>
      <section className="topbar-for-information">
        <div>
          <span>“FREE SHIPPING ON ALL DOMESTIC INDIAN ORDERS OVER &#8377;700.”</span>
        </div>
      </section>

      <header id="topbar-container">
        <section class="navbar-container">
          <div id="side-menu-icon" class="header-left header-cont">
            <Menu></Menu>
          </div>

          <div class="logo header-middle header-cont">
            <Link to="/">
              <img class="header-logo-image lazyautosizes lazyloaded" data-sizes="auto"
                src="https://cdn11.bigcommerce.com/s-9srn18to/stencil/a82ba480-88a4-013b-ff0c-3edc8172940f/e/27b3c0d0-8375-013b-6337-2642882715b5/img/logo.gif"
                data-src="https://cdn11.bigcommerce.com/s-9srn18to/stencil/a82ba480-88a4-013b-ff0c-3edc8172940f/e/27b3c0d0-8375-013b-6337-2642882715b5/img/logo.gif"
                alt="Bohemian Traders" title="Bohemian Traders" sizes="328px" />
            </Link>
          </div>


          <div class="header-right header-cont">

            <div class="header-logo span-cart-num">
              <Cart></Cart>
              <span className='cart-quantity'>{products.length}</span>
            </div>

            <div class="toggleLoginCard header-logo">
              <HiOutlineUserCircle />
            </div>


            <form action="" onSubmit={submitHandler}>
              <div className="searchBox">
                <input type="text" name="" id="" placeholder="Search Your Fit..." value={query} onChange={onChange} />
                <p id='rightGapSearch'><IoSearchOutline /></p>
              </div>
            </form>

            <script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.esm.js"></script>
            <script noModule src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.js"></script>
          </div>

        </section>
      </header>
    </>
  )
}

export default Navbar;
```

and here is the search page:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { IoOptions } from "react-icons/io5";
import List from '../../components/ListC/List';
import { IoCloseOutline } from "react-icons/io5";
import { Drawer } from "antd";
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import useFetch from "../../hooks/useFetch";

export const Search = () => {

  const catId = parseInt(useParams().id);
  const [maxPrice, setMaxPrice] = useState(1000)
  const [sort, setSort] = useState(null);
  const [selectedSubCats, setSelectedSubCats] = useState([]);

  const mystyleFilter = {
    background: "rgb(18, 18, 18)",
    color: "#ffffff"
};

  const { data, loading, error } = useFetch(
    `/sub-categories?[filters][categories][id][$eq]=${catId}`
  );

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const value = e.target.value;
    const isChecked = e.target.checked;

    setSelectedSubCats(
      isChecked
        ? [...selectedSubCats, value]
        : selectedSubCats.filter((item) => item !== value)
    );
  };

  console.log(selectedSubCats);

const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div className='productPage-container'>

      <div className="filter-icon-container unselectable" onClick={()=>{setVisible(true)}}>
        <span>FILTERS <IoOptions className='filter-icon' /></span>
      </div>

      <Drawer 
      open={visible} 
      closable = {false}
      onClose={()=>setVisible(false)}
      bodyStyle={mystyleFilter}
      keyboard={true}
      >

        <div className="filter-top">
          <div className="filter-top-left">
            <span>FILTERS</span>
          </div>
          <div className="filter-top-right">
            <IoCloseOutline onClick={()=>setVisible(false)}/>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className="filter-bottom">
          <div className="filterItem">
            <h2>PRODUCT CATEGORIES</h2>
            {data?.map((item) => (
            <div className="inputItem" key={item.id}>
              <input
                type="checkbox"
                id={item.id}
                value={item.id}
                onChange={handleChange}
              />
              <label htmlFor={item.id}>{item.attributes.title}</label>
            </div>
          ))}
          </div>
          <div className="filterItem">
            <h2>FILTER BY PRICE</h2>
            <div className="inputItem">
              <span>0</span>
              <input type="range" name="" id="" min={0} max={1000} onChange={(e) => setMaxPrice(e.target.value)} />
              <span>{maxPrice}</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="filterItem">
            <h2>SORT BY</h2>
            <div className="inputItem">
              <input type="radio" id="asc" value="asc" name="price" onChange={e => setSort("asc")} />
              <label htmlFor="asc">Price (lowest first)</label>
            </div>
            <div className="inputItem">
              <input type="radio" id="asc" value="asc" name="price" onChange={e => setSort("desc")} />
              <label htmlFor="asc">Price (highest first)</label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </Drawer>

      <div className="right-products">
        <List catId={catId} maxPrice={maxPrice} sort={sort} subCats={selectedSubCats}/>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Search;
```

Should I use Redux for making query globally available? or use some strapi plugins?

I tried using Redux but I don't know Redux.